# Retaining an input from a button for further clock cycles (Verilog FPGA)

Tags: loops, verilog, fpga

In my current FPGA Verilog project, I am required to use a button on the FPGA board and make it such that once the button has been pressed the input remains 1 even after the button has been released until a certain condition is met.

However, I'm struggling to understand how this would work logically. On hardware since the input of the button is being checked every clock cycle how would I make it such that after the initial button press of producing an input of 1 from the button, Verilog uses 1 for the foreseeable clock cycles until a condition is met?

Context: For a Verilog FPGA VGA game project I'm trying to replicate the jump from geometry dash where the block does the full jump after an initial input 1 (tap on the screen) and remains 1 (regardless of whether the screen is held or released) until the jump is complete and the block is touching the floor. Below is a code for what I've managed to achieve.

```
module game_top #(parameter
    
    FLR_POS = 11'd696,
    BLK_HGT = 11'd32,
    MAX_JMP = 11'd164)(
    
    input clk,
    input [4:0] btn,
    output [3:0] pix_r,
    output [3:0] pix_g,
    output [3:0] pix_b,
    output hsync,
    output vsync);
    
    wire pix_clk;           //internal wires and regs
    wire [3:0] draw_r;      //has to be a wire because combinational logic not using a clock in drawcon
    wire [3:0] draw_g;      //has to be a wire because combinational logic not using a clock in drawcon
    wire [3:0] draw_b;      //has to be a wire because combinational logic not using a clock in drawcon
    wire [10:0] curr_x;     //current location on screen x pos
    wire [10:0] curr_y;     //current location on screen x pos
    wire [10:0] obspos_x;
    wire [10:0] obspos_y;
    wire flag_1;
 
    reg game_clk = 0;
    reg [20:0] clk_div = 0;
    reg [10:0] blkpos_x = 11'd703; //center of screen 
    reg [10:0] blkpos_y = 11'd424;
    reg top = 0; 
           
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if(clk_div == 100000000/120) begin //clk divider
            clk_div <= 20'd0;
            game_clk <= !game_clk;   //60hz produced
        end else begin 
            clk_div <= clk_div + 1;
        end
    end
    
    always@(posedge game_clk) begin     //button inputs, jump logic 
   
        if(btn[0]) begin                            // resets block to starting position
            blkpos_x <= 11'd503;
            blkpos_y <= FLR_POS - BLK_HGT;
        end

        // if the button is pressed block keeps raising and if released the block falls 
        // But if the block raises too high then it automatically starts falling to the floor ignoring button  

        else if(btn[1]) begin                       
            blkpos_x <= blkpos_x;                   
            if (blkpos_y > MAX_JMP) begin           
                blkpos_y <= blkpos_y - 11'd10;
            end   
            else begin
                top <= 11'd1;
            end     
        end
        
        else if (top == 1 || (btn[1] && top == 1)) begin    
            blkpos_x <= blkpos_x;                           
            if (blkpos_y + BLK_HGT <= FLR_POS) begin
                blkpos_y <= blkpos_y + 11'd10;
            end   
            else begin
                blkpos_y <= blkpos_y;
                top <= 11'd0;
            end   
        end

        else begin 
            blkpos_x <= blkpos_x;
            
            if (blkpos_y + BLK_HGT >= FLR_POS) begin
                blkpos_y <= blkpos_y;
            end
            else begin
                blkpos_y <= blkpos_y + 11'd10;
            end   
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the "button pressed" signal directly to represent this state. Instead, it should be represented by another `reg`.

If in one clock cycle the "button pressed" signal is 1, the state should be set to 1.

> until a certain condition is met.

If in a clock cycle the "button pressed" signal is 0 and this "certain condition" is met, the state should be set to 0.